# Identify submit button click of UIWebview

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uibutton, getelementbyid

I have a UIWebView page with multiple button . Need to identify which button is clicked of the `UIWebView.`

Page source for UIWebview load contents:

```
        <form action="settings_personal.php" data-ajax="false" method="post">   
            <input type="submit" name ="btn_settings_personal" value=" Goals (Personal data) " data-icon="star" data-theme="g" />
        </form> 

        <form action="settings_global.php" data-ajax="false" method="post"> 
            <input type="submit" name ="btn_settings_global" value=" Settings " data-icon="gear" data-theme="g" />
        </form>
        <form action="" data-ajax="false" method="post">    
            <input type="submit" name ="btn_web_access" value=" Web Plattform Access " data-icon="plus" data-theme="h" />
        </form>
```

I need to identify  button clicked for  'btn_web_access' named button ???

I have implemented following :

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

 NSString* clicked = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('btn_web_access').click();"];

    NSLog(@"CLICK %@",clicked);

}
```

but its of no use..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString call will just trigger a new button click event. That does not seem useful, as you are asking on how to identify which button has been clicked, not how to click a button programmatically. See my answer on wether it helps you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use the request's URL attribute to distinguish the load request's target:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType{

    NSLog(@"url: %@", [[request URL] absoluteString]);

    return YES;

}
```

Based on the URL being called, you know which button (or even any link) of your currently shown webpage was clicked. Then take the action being needed and don't forget to return a BOOL value indicating wether or not to actually load the requested URL.

In Swift you might have

```
func webView(webView:UIWebView,
          shouldStartLoadWithRequest request:NSURLRequest,
          navigationType:UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {
    if (navigationType == .FormSubmitted)
        {
        print("was the 'submit' form")
        }

    let u = request.mainDocumentURL
    print("local or remote url was " ,u)

    return true // allow the form to in fact send the form
    }
```

Comment: But Alex webpage is not containg any action , pls check the below <form action="" data-ajax="false" method="post">    
            <input type="submit" name ="btn_web_access" value=" Web Plattform Access " data-icon="plus" data-theme="h" />
        </form>

Comment: Just set any arbitrary link, which will help you identify your button, inside the action parameter. When a user clicks this button, just return a NO in shouldStartLoadWithRequest. So this click will not result in an actual page load inside the webview.

Comment: Alex due you any other option like to identify Clicked button's name of the UIWebview.

Comment: Another approach would be similar: 1) Inside HTML, don't submit the form directly on button click. Instead, call a javascript function, that saves a button identifier inside a global variable **and** submits the form then, if necessary. 2) Get the current javascript button identifier value inside shouldStartLoadWithRequest method by stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. But you still need an action parameter set to every form.

Comment: Alex i got another option to get the Value of the UIWebview button i.e the name which will be easier to identify...BY below code  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType  { NSString* value1 = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByName('btn_web_access')[0].value"];
    NSLog(@"Uersname  :  %@",value1);  }

Answer (score 0):

Do this with HTML Code

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
    (NSURLRequest *)request navigationType: 
    (UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
        if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"inapp"]) {
            if ([request.URL.host isEqualToString:@"capture"]) {
            // do capture action
        }  
        return NO;
     }  

   return YES;
}
```