# User permission from webViewKit button click

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

Using swift 4 and IOS 12 ,i am using a webViewKit to load a website. One of the features of the web app is to scan qrcode, i have successfully loaded the website but i am still struggling how to access the device camera to scan qr code, in android everything works fine including this qr code scanner using webView onPermissionRequest method. I have already tried this
[Key       :  Privacy - Camera Usage Description   in info.plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631256/request-permission-for-camera-and-library-in-ios-10-info-plist) 
  and also adding these lines of codes here [AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_ios) on url load before pressing the web button to scan qr code. According to our web developer this button press executes a javascript undefined function, but i don't know how to make webViewKit respond to this button click event and the hardest part is that there are no logs or NSLogs to evaluate. I am new to IOS development for about almost a month. Thank you

```
var WebCodeCamJS = function(element) {
'use strict';
this.Version = {
    name: 'WebCodeCamJS',
    version: '2.7.0',
    author: 'Tóth András',
};
var mediaDevices = window.navigator.mediaDevices;
mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(c) {
    return new Promise(function(y, n) {
        (window.navigator.getUserMedia || window.navigator.mozGetUserMedia || window.navigator.webkitGetUserMedia).call(navigator, c, y, n);
    });
}

HTMLVideoElement.prototype.streamSrc = ('srcObject' in HTMLVideoElement.prototype) ? function(stream) {
    this.srcObject = !!stream ? stream : null;
} : function(stream) {
    if (!!stream) {
        this.src = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(stream);
    } else {
        this.removeAttribute('src');
    }
};
```

Above code is a js function named webcodecamjs.js that is being executed from a button click event on the web page. I found similar problem with solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513521/how-to-get-camera-and-microphone-access-in-wkwebview-cocoa) , but i'm not quite sure how to implement it, it says

> 1. Now Add JS file (WebRTC.js) that defines various WebRTC classes, functions & passes the calls to the WKWebView.
> 2. In the WKWebView inject the script at the document start:

where do i put this WebRTC.js file? what i did was to create a new file in my ios project and named it WebRTC.js , i also tried renaming it to webcodecamjs.js like what we have in web js files, how i did it in func viewDidAppear

```
let contentController = WKUserContentController()

    contentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")
    let script = try! String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "webcodecamjs", withExtension: "js")!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    contentController.addUserScript(WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true))
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences
    configuration.userContentController = contentController
    configuration.allowsPictureInPictureMediaPlayback = true


     webView.navigationDelegate = self
    webView.configuration.preferences = configuration.preferences
    WKWebView.load(webView)(NSURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: encodedLoginUrl)! as URL) as URLRequest)
```

webView is a

> @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView

not declared as below

> var webView: WKWebView

that's why i can't do something like below, cause it gives me 'weak' warning

> webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect.zero, configuration: config)

Comment: Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11896985/identify-submit-button-click-of-uiwebview

Comment: @MahakMittal i appreciate your response , i have already visited that site before and tried to implement those accepted answers but unfortunately some of the answers are not written in swift , there is one there but it is not supported in ios 12 anymore. I also tried this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509990/migrating-from-uiwebview-to-wkwebview] but still no luck..

Answer (score 0):

Could you add code snippet to check?

Comment: You don't need to add js file in your code. You just need to add following function :
   func webView(webView:UIWebView,
          shouldStartLoadWithRequest request:NSURLRequest,
          navigationType:UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
    {
    let u = request.mainDocumentURL
    print("local or remote url was " ,u)

    return true // allow the form to in fact send the form
    }

This will allow you to get the action of submit  button

Comment: In the url you can check for particular action and can do whatever you want.

Comment: it gave me warning  'UIWebView' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: No longer supported; please adopt WKWebView.' , how ever there is a migration from shouldStartLoadWithRequest here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37509990/migrating-from-uiwebview-to-wkwebview] , but still no response in my logs, after i click the button the method is not executed

Comment: Does the code working fine with UIWebview? If you do not convert it with WKWebView.

Comment: No it doesn't work either .. i think what i really need to figure out is how am i going to make WKWebView listen for onclick events that involves javascript. If i catch that event or receive the onclick event thats the time i can figure out when to invoke user permission pop up to open the device camera and scan the qr code

Comment: by the way i am now using WKWebView and set to viewController view like  self.view = webView